# How can i save on arraylist the response that i receive from my api?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

i'm new on retrofit and i want to save the response from my api like an object on an array list.

i've search solutions but i dont know how callback method works and i can't understand very well.

```java
public ArrayList<Match> recolectar_partido(){

        final ArrayList<Match> datos=new ArrayList<Match>();

        Call<List<MatchResponse>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getmatch();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MatchResponse>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<MatchResponse>> call, Response<List<MatchResponse>> response) {
                matchlist=response.body();
                for (MatchResponse fix:matchlist) {
                    Integer idfix=fix.getId_fixture();
                    Integer idsta=fix.getId_stadium();
                    String  fecha=fix.getFecha();
                    String  hora=fix.getHora();
                    Match variable= new Match(idfix,idsta,fecha,hora);
                    datos.add(variable);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<MatchResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error de conexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
     return datos;
    }
```

i want the arraylist to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Do `call.execute()` instead of `enqueue`.
E.g.

```
final ArrayList<Match> datos=new ArrayList<Match>();

Call<List<MatchResponse>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getmatch();
matchlist= call.execute().body();
for (MatchResponse fix:matchlist) {
    Integer idfix=fix.getId_fixture();
    Integer idsta=fix.getId_stadium();
    String  fecha=fix.getFecha();
    String  hora=fix.getHora();
    Match variable= new Match(idfix,idsta,fecha,hora);
    datos.add(variable);
}
return datos;
```

Comment: i get java.lang.RuntimeException

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace of exception?